# Enqueue Script in custom plugin before other

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I've got a conflict with another plugin which is blocking the JS in my custom plugin with the hook:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '<FOREIGN-PLUGIN>');
```

Is there a way to enqueue my JS before all other plugins?

I tried already to set priority like

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '<FOREIGN-PLUGIN>', 1);
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '<MY-PLUGIN>', 2);
```

but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `remove_action()` to remove the other plugin's action, add yours, then add back the other plugin's action?

Comment: your plugin should be independent of other plugin actions. that will avoid a lot of headaches in future development and customization. But if you insist on doing so, try `wp_deregister_script( 'script-handle' )` then enqueue your script, other script. To register script:  `wp_register_script(....parameters....)`  and to enqueue script : `wp_enqueue_script('script-handle')`

Answer (score 0):

Use dependencies. Dependencies are scripts that your script relies upon to be loaded first. The `<FOREIGN-PLUGIN>`  in the example should be the handle that script was enqueued with.

```
$deps = array('<FOREIGN-PLUGIN>');
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps);
```

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this, as it's the correct answer and the correct way to enqueue scripts or CSS that are reliant upon other scripts/CSS